# Run CodeIgniter site from Command Line

Tags: php, html, macos, codeigniter, console

OK, what I need is fairly straightforward.

I've got a website, built on CodeIgniter, with controllers, etc, and I'd like to be able to test it using the Console.

**E.g.**

```
http://localhost/mysite/some-controller?u=someParam

$> ci some-controller?u=someParam
```

Is that possible in some way? And if so, how?

---

**Sidenote :** I'm using XAMPP for Mac OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Try this in command line:

```
php /path/to/index.php/controller/function/param1/param2/param3 ...
```

or

```
php /path/to/index.php controller function param1 param2 param3 ...
```